# How to get value in function and replace variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Now I get data from firebase

```
database = firebase.database();
var ref = database.ref('urls');
ref.on('value', gotData, errData);

function errData(err){
    console.log('Error!');
    console.log(err);
}

function gotData(data){
    result = data.val() 
    const urls = Object.keys(result)
                 .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 5)
                 .map(key => ({url: 's/price/' + result[key].url_site + '/'}))
    console.log(urls)
}
```

Result urls is

```
[ { url: '/cream/' },
  { url: '/salmon/' },
  { url: '/salmon-s/' } ]
```

I need to send data in urls replace as below

```
var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({ 
    hostname: 'xxx.com',
    urls: [ { url: 'xxx' },
  { url: 'xxx' },
  { url: 'xxx' } ]
});
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
const a = [ { url: '/cream/' },
  { url: '/salmon/' },
  { url: '/salmon-s/' } ]
  
const sm = Object.assign({ hostname: 'xxx.com'}, { urls: a})

console.log(JSON.stringify(sm, null, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a `createSitemap()` function and pass the urls to it from `gotData()`

```
function gotData(data){
    result = data.val() 
    const urls = Object.keys(result)
                 .filter(key => result[key].last_res > 5)
                 .map(key => ({url: 's/price/' + result[key].url_site + '/'}))
    createSitemap(urls)
}

function createSitemap(urls) {
    var sitemap = sm.createSitemap({ 
        hostname: 'xxx.com',
        urls: urls
    });
}
```